# "Saving" value in input type="hidden" Chrome alternative

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, google-chrome

I tried to detect if the page is loaded using the back button of the browser to force a refresh. Therefore I used

```
   <input type="hidden" id="refresh" name="refresh" value="no">
   <script>
   if ($("#refresh").val() == "no")
   {
      $("#refresh").val("yes");
   }
   else
   {
      parent.location.reload(true);
   }
   </script>
```

which worked fine with IE, Edge, Firefox - but not in Chrome. I searched a bit and here is the answer: Chrome does not support the advantage of "saving" values in a hidden input. Do you know any other possibilities to "save" and request a changed value after turning back to the page?

Comment: It's not going to give you the solution you want but it's interesting as an alternative: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage allows to save data to a "database" which is stored locally.

Comment: @Albert this solution works perfectly, nice! Thanks.

Comment: don't forget to post your own answer and mark it as the answer of your question ;)

Comment: Yeah I already did but thanks for remind me. Needs 2 days to accept :) @Albert

Comment: since I've only posted a reference to this page, if you'd be so kind, post the respective code with a small explanation? That'd be really nice.

Comment: Code is posted, but I think there is not much to explain :) @Albert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution by @Albert in the comments.

```
        if (!localStorage.getItem("refresh"))
        {
            localStorage.setItem("refresh", "yes");
        }
        else
        {
            localStorage.removeItem("refresh");
            parent.location.reload(true);
        }
```

Works perfectly in IE, Edge, Firefox and Chrome. If you try it your own, dont forget to remove the item. If you want to get a clear Storage when closing your Browser, you need sessionStorage instead.